# unix2dos not recogonizing outfile

Tags: centos, files, filesystems, terminal

I typed `unix2dos /path/to/filename_unix.txt /path/to/filename_dos.txt` in the CentOS 7 terminal, but I got the following in response:

```
unix2dos: converting file /path/to/filename_unix.txt to DOS format ...
unix2dos: /path/to/filename_dos.txt: No such file or directory
unix2dos: Skipping /path/to/filename_dos.txt, not a regular file.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: these utilities usally work best as filters, i.e. `unix2dos < unix_file.txt > dos_file.txt` or similar should be the preferred way of using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing -n switch of command. You have to type:

```
unix2dos -n /path/to/filename_unix.txt /path/to/filename_dos.txt
```

As you typed it I think unix2dos is looking for two files to convert. So now your filename_unix.txt should be converted to dos.